# Why padding-left and height are not working the same as padding-bottom and width?

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand what is happening behind the scene.
Here is the thing. When I gave the first dive width and padding-bottom or top, it takes effect and box is showing up. So I'm assuming that I have chosen the width and then change the height by padding and it's working in this way. However, with this idea, I thought that by giving height and padding-left or right it should work the same but it doesn't. So I really appreciate if someone explains it to me.

first div:

[image: first box:]

second div:

[image]

```css
.square{
  background-color: red;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
}
.square2{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30%;
  padding-left: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because padding in % is always related to `width`?

Comment: is that a question or an answer? :-)

Comment: I suspect this is a duplicate question but I'm pressed for time in trying to find the dupe target.

Comment: Aha....found it.